# Python return list not working for some reason

Tags: python, error-handling

I've been trying to work on this assignment but for some reason the function I wrote won't return the list I specified and throws a `name 'numbers' is not defined` error at me when printing the list outside the function.

```
def inputNumbers():
    try:
        initial_number_input = int(input("Please enter the first number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("This is not a number.")
        return inputNumbers()
    else:
        numbers = []
        numbers.append(initial_number_input)
        if initial_number_input == 0:
            return numbers
        else:
            i = 0
            while True:
                try:
                    number_input = int(input("Please enter the next number: "))
                except ValueError:
                    print("This is not a number.")
                    continue
                else:
                    numbers.append(number_input)
                    i += 1
                    if number_input == 0:
                        break
            return numbers

inputNumbers()
print(numbers)
```

I'm still very new to programming so I am open to whatever suggestions you may have :D

Note that if I `print(numbers)` above `return numbers` at the end of the function, it does print the list.

Thanks

Comment: You also need to assign the value you return to some variable: `nums = inputNumbers(); print(nums)`

Comment: `numbers` is a local variable. You can't access it from outside the function. Instead, use `numbers = inputNumbers()`, and then do `print(numbers)`

Comment: This worked. Didn't know I had to assign a variable for the function to return to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return a value from a function it needs to be assigned to something. At the moment you are returning `numbers` but nothing is using it.

To actually use the returned value your last 2 lines should be

```
numbers = inputNumbers()
print(numbers)
```

You can also just print the returned value without assigning it to a variable with

```
print(inputNumbers())
```